# Idiom for re-raising an old ugly affair better left alone

Tags: idiom-requests

I can't think of an idiom for dredging out, revisiting or raising mention of and old ugly affair that is better left alone.

Comment: Reopening a can of worms.

Comment: @Xanne I did actually end up using re-opening a can of worms, so if you post as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2):

Some pertinent idioms:

To do this is to [open old wounds](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/open+old+wounds).

To advise someone not to do this: [Let sleeping dogs lie.](https://www.theidioms.com/let-sleeping-dogs-lie/)

To "open a can of worms"? I think not -- the unpleasant matter figuratively referred to there might be a new one rather than an old one.